# Sonar Custom Method using Java

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have to create a custom rule in SonarQube using Java, but I don't know where to start. I need a rule that checks if all the methods of a class are Protected. How can I start? If you have a good reference or something that explains step by step how to make custom rules, I will be grateful.
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go through the documentation of the sonar java plugin ?
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+Java

More precisely have a look at github project sonar-examples : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules